# Pass multiple params to the current page with form_tag in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I want to pass several params in the url of the current page with a `form_tag` but I have failed to understand to correct syntax. 
Quick explanation: I have outfits (model) that has many outfit_items (model).
Each outfit_item has available_sizes (attribute of outfit_item). All of this is set by the admin. 
Then on the show page of an Outfit, (for example `http://localhost:3000/outfits/7`) I want to display the available sizes for each outfit_item, let the visitor pick his size for each item and press submit. The selected sizes should then appear in the URL.
Here is what I have in my show view, at the url  :

```
<%= form_tag(@outfit_path, :method=>'post') do %>
    <% @outfit.outfit_items.each do |outfit_item| %>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <%= image_tag outfit_item.item_image.url(:medium) %><br>
            <% sizes = outfit_item.available_sizes.split(",") %>
            <%= select_tag "size#{outfit_item.category}", "<option>#{sizes[1]}</option><option>#{sizes[2]}</option><option>#{sizes[3]}</option><option>#{sizes[4]}</option>".html_safe, :class => "input-mini select-mini" %><br>
            <%= hidden_field_tag "size#{outfit_item.category}", value: outfit_item.category %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
            <%= submit_tag "ok size"  %>
<% end %>
```

I want to land on this url when I hit submit

```
http://localhost:3000/outfits/7?size1=42&size2=L&size3=S&size4=44
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
<%= form_tag(outfit_path(@outfit), :method=>'get') do %>
  <% @outfit.outfit_items.each do |outfit_item| %>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
          <%= image_tag outfit_item.item_image.url(:medium) %><br>
          <% sizes = outfit_item.available_sizes.split(",") %>
          <%= select_tag "size#{outfit_item.category}", options_for_select(sizes), :class => "input-mini select-mini" %><br>
          <%= hidden_field_tag "size#{outfit_item.category}", value: outfit_item.category %>
      </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= submit_tag "ok size"  %>
<% end %>
```

Some assumptions:

Notes:

- `outfits_path(@outfit)` would normally (from convention) be `"/outfits/<outfit id>"`, so that's what i've used here - this is what i'd expect from convention
- If you want to land on the url, ie make it public, you should make it a GET request, not a post request.  so i've changed the form to make a GET  request
- you've got a hidden_field_tag in there.  This will show up in
  your url as well, so it's impossible to get the exact url you desire
  AND have the hidden field tag in there.
- `options_for_select(sizes)` is a much nicer way of generating a bunch of option tags
- I get the feeling that there's a much nicer way to do what you're trying to do here, but without knowing more about your schema i can't say what.

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this. Hope it helps.

```
<%= form_tag(@outfit_path, url: your_path(size1: value1, size2: value2, ......)  :method=>'post') do %>
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. Not sure how to handle this. I want the selected value of each field to be passed as a param, I don't have any size value defined when  the form_tag opens.